# Extract columns to another Excel sheet, in certain order

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large datafile in Excel with about 240 columns each representing a variable. As I only need 56 of these variables, I want to extract the corresponding columns to another Excel sheet.

I managed to do so with a macro using the following code (which I found here [Extract columns from excel to new sheet as repeated process](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother/extract-columns-from-excel-to-new-sheet-as/d825f54f-4f19-42da-881b-95ae0af74b04)):

```
Public Sub extractCol()
    Set range1 = Range("A:D, BI:BI, BQ:BQ,CL:CL,CM:CN,CT:CT,DB:DB")
    range1.Copy
    Set newbook = Workbooks.Add
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Because this new datafile will be more clear and convenient if I have the columns in a certain order (e.g.: DB - BI - CL - CM - CN - A:D), I wonder whether there is something I can add to this code to put the columns in the order I want in the new file?

Or is there an entirely different way to do this whole extracting and sorting of columns in excel that doesn't use a (or this) macro?

Comment: You can extract them one bye one: Copy the column you like first at first and paste it then copy the column you want to be second and paste it and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to do it would be to read the first table in to an array (see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx for examples), copy values from the first array into a second array in the order that you want to paste, and then write the array to a new table.

Working with arrays instead of copy/paste is orders of magnitude faster.

This example reads a range with three columns into an array and then picks column 1 and 3 and puts them into a new array.  Should be enough to get you started!

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub test()
Dim range1 as Range, destination as Range
dim sourcedata() as variant
dim targetdata() as variant

Set range1 = Range("B1:D50")
Set destination = Range("K1")
sourcedata = range1.Value2

Redim targetdata(UBound(sourcedata, 1), 2)

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 to Ubound(sourcedata, 1)
    targetdata(i, 1) = sourcedata(i, 1)
    targetdata(i, 2) = sourcedata(i, 3)
Next

destination.Resize(Ubound(targetdata, 1), Ubound(targetdata, 2)).Value = targetdata
End Sub
```